# How to mount a samba share directory without password?

Tags: mount, password, samba

There is a share directory behind samba, and I add samba user `test` with the command `smbpasswd -a -n test` to make no password for user `test`.

But when I need to access the shared directory from another Linux/Windows, can I use `test` user to mount the directory without password?

Comment: Wait...What !!! You want to use `username` but not the `password` ?

Comment: @SHW Yes, for some security reason, I must use the username, because I can't set the directory mask as 777.

Comment: I have already add `null password = yes` in `smb.conf`.

Comment: What about `force user = test`. Example of an open [share](http://pastebin.com/H5vBPxai).